# DocumentFilter.insertString() is never called

Tags: java, swing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [documentFilter.insert never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844848/documentfilter-insert-never-called)

The overriden `insertString(...)` method never gets called. Am I missing something? A piece of code:

```
package jaba;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    public Main() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(640, 480);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(txt);
        Document doc = txt.getDocument();
        if (doc instanceof AbstractDocument) {
            ((AbstractDocument)doc).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
                @Override
                public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, 
                        int offset, String string, AttributeSet att)
                throws BadLocationException {
                    if (string.toLowerCase().contains("ass")) {
                        super.insertString(fb, offset, "###", att);
                    } else {
                        super.insertString(fb, offset, string, att);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            txt.setText("error setting filter");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private JTextArea txt = new JTextArea(40, 40);
}
```